# Deleting Custom Site Columns under a content type

Tags: sharepoint, contenttype

I have a custom site column and have added that custom site column to a Content Type "System Media Collection" which is present inside "_Hidden" Content Type Group. When I tried to delete that particular site column present under that System Media Collection CT, the deleting is not happening nor throwing an error.

I used the below code to delete:

```
contenttype.FieldLinks.Delete("site column name");
contenttype.Update(true);
```

Note: the System Media Collection content type is not associated with any list.

I couldn't figure out the details about the above Content Type.

Let me know if some one faced similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am here to post on this thread 2 years later, which is the number one google result for "system media library" search to say.. in our case, when the column showed up in system media library I couldn't delete it, despite my attempts.  However, what I found is that the site column ALSO existed in another variation that we had created.  Once I deleted it from the other variation I was able to remove it.